# Were Stack Exchange Data dumps removed from Archive.org?

Tags: support, data-dump

It seems that Stack Exchange data dumps are [no longer available at Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange):

> This item is no longer available.
> Items may be taken down for various reasons, including by decision of the uploader or due to a violation of our Terms of Use.

Where can we access them? Or is this a temporary issue?